# Load Google Places API when Maps is already loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have this widget that uses Google Maps and the Places API, that integrates on client websites. One of these sites already uses Maps, so I have an error  `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

The problem is that the site does not load the places API. So I need to load it without loading Maps. Is that even possible?

The site uses
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=fr`

when I use
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=fr&callback=swnGeolocation.initCallback`

The latter loads both `main` and `places` scripts. How can I load places independently?

---

**EDIT:** It works if I use a modified version of the url generated by the bootstraper.

The standard way to include google maps library generates the following url:
`http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/15a/intl/fr_ALL/main.js`

`http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/15a/intl/fr_ALL/places.js` is also a valid url I can use. What I'm worried is it clearly refers to a specific version of the library, and by hard-coding it it may someday no more be compatible with the maps library. That's a workaround, but not a clean one.

---

**EDIT 2**: A new version of Maps API has been published during the last 24 hours (from 3.18.15a to 3.19.0), and as I feared it breaks the poor fix described above. I wish there were some proper way to do that.